# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/smiley.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, php, android-studio

I am uploading a file to my php webserver, but however I'm getting the permission denied. It works for mp3 and image extensions. However for .csv, i'll get that error when i hit upload. I'm new to this and I can't figure out if its the permission issue on android or the upload doesn't support uploading of csv. Appreciate any guidance or help. Thanks!

**My upload code:**

```
private class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            String sourceFileUri = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/smiley.csv";
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

            Log.d("myTag", ""+sourceFile.isFile());
            if (sourceFile.isFile()) {

                try {
                    String upLoadServerUri = "https://www.mywebsite.tk/upload.php?";

                    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                            sourceFile);
                    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE",
                            "multipart/form-data");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                            "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("bill", sourceFileUri);

                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bill\";filename=\""
                            + sourceFileUri + "\"" + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0) {

                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math
                                .min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,
                                bufferSize);

                    }

                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file
                    // data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                            + lineEnd);

                    // Responses from the server (code and message)
                    serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    String serverResponseMessage = conn
                            .getResponseMessage();

                    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                        // messageText.setText(msg);
                        //Toast.makeText(ctx, "File Upload Complete.",
                        //      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // recursiveDelete(mDirectory1);

                    }
                    // close the streams //
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    // dialog.dismiss();
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                // dialog.dismiss();

            } // End else block


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // dialog.dismiss();

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("myTag", "I iz completed");
        return "Executed";
    }
}
```

**My PHP Server Code**

```
<?php


if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['bill']['tmp_name'])) {
$uploads_dir = './';
                       $tmp_name = $_FILES['bill']['tmp_name'];
                       $pic_name = $_FILES['bill']['name'];
                       move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir.$pic_name);
                       }
          else{
              echo "File not uploaded successfully.";
      }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get a file from android, use File constructor with path and file.
e.g.
new File(path, file);

[My project: check File#getFile(Context context, String fileName)](https://github.com/Gabriele-P03/GreenLand/blob/d3981968045e17f72255b0772db09a5e7a0cfcb0/app/src/main/java/com/greenland/utils/Files.java#L41)

Comment: p.s.  Context#getFileDirs returns the path of your app directory

Comment: Hello, sorry I don't really get it, but uri should work as well? Or specifically for csv extensions, using uri wouldnt work?
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File

Comment: File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);                                                                    
String sourceFileUri = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/smiley.csv";                                                  As you have written, you aren't using URI. You instance a new File using a String... not a URI!

Comment: I have changed to the following but im still getting the same error: String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download"; 
File sourceFile = new File(path, "smiley.csv");

Comment: I've never used HttpURLConnection, yet. But read the docs! It says that #setRequestProperty(String, String) ---> Not a URI or a File!

Comment: About DataStream, it is useful for binary file(mp3 ecc...), instead you're sending/receiving string. So use InputStream/OutputStream! Another tip: when you wanna send bytes, convert them as byte, not send as any other type( you could get some errors on conversion)

Comment: Oh yeaps! But is there anyways to bypass it? I've noted the httpConnection is a string. So Now im back to the same problem even with File sourceFile = new File(path, "smiley.csv");, really appreciate your help so far.

Comment: Yeah. But as I said, HttpURLConnection#setRequestProperty(String, String) accepts only strings as params. But you're giving a string and a URI...

Comment: Oh yeaps i've change it to strings instead for the http, but now the error is back the File to the `File sourceFile = new File(path, "smiley.csv");` I've changed it from string of the path like you said to the following, but the same error still comes up

Comment: Man, I am not understanding anything anymore, with all these answer! LOL! So, please, click on "Add Another Question"(below) and explain: your achieve, where you get stuck on now, post the current code and post the Log of the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66168945/java-io-filenotfoundexception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-when-uplo
Hi i've added another question with the updated codes. LOL thank you so much!