# FileNotFoundException when trying to screenshot

Tags: java, android

Below is my MainActivity and Manifest file. I am trying to implement a screenshot in my app which then gives the option to open the screenshot using other applications. When I click the button in the main activity nothing is happening. It keeps throwing java.io.FileNotFoundException like so

W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/ScreenShooter/2021-02-19_07:45:59.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Is there a way to solve this?

```
package com.levirs.example.screenshooter;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                screenshoot();
            }
        });
    }

    private void screenshoot() {
        Date date = new Date();
        CharSequence now = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", date);
        String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ScreenShooter/" + now + ".jpg";

        View root = getWindow().getDecorView();
        root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(root.getDrawingCache());
        root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File file = new File(filename);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();

            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.levirs.example.screenshooter">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: If you are testing your app on Android 11 you should check this documentation on storage privacy changes https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Comment: what do you need exactly ? implement screenshot and open other apps i didn't get it sorry

Comment: You asked this before but deleted that post with the hints you got. You have nothing done with the hints.

Answer (score 3):

its seems like you are access the directory which not exist make sure its exist if you are using default screenshots folder then replace this line

```
      Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ScreenShooter/" + now + ".jpg";
```

to

```
      Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/Screenshots/" + now + ".jpg";
```

but this getExternalStorageDirectory is depricated now so use this one

```
      getFilesDir()+ "/Pictures/Screenshots/" + now + ".jpg";
```

Comment: how do i make sure the directory exists in my code?

Comment: File file = new File(filename);  if (file.isFile()) {Log.d("Tag","Yes Its exist")}

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to instance a file on a path only via string which represents path+fileName.

Instead you should instance a new File with path separated from the fileName.
[A similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167557/java-io-filenotfoundexception-storage-emulated-0-download-smiley-csv-open-fai/66167709#66167709)