# When create a directory in android 10 app crash but android 11 it's work well

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-file

-I have also add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in manifest.

-It is issue in android 10 and below.it is nice work in android 11.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"></application>
```

My code

```
  File vidDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                   (Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + File.separator + "HeepVideo"); if(!vidDir.exists()) {
         vidDir.mkdirs();
        System.out.println("Created");
      }

 String videoName = "Video_" + uuid.toString() + ".mp4";
 File fileVideo = new File(vidDir.getAbsolutePath(), videoName);
 
 if (fileVideo.exists()){
    fileVideo.createNewFile();
 }
```

Error :

> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.870 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /storage/emulated/0/Movies/HeepVideo/Video_d545dce1-e554-4372-b480-bc0a15912efc.mp4:
> open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.871 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.871 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at
> java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:235)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.871 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at
> java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:186)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.871 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at
> com.example.myapplication.activity.VideoPreviewActivity.shareVideoInOtherApp(VideoPreviewActivity.java:497)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.871 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at
> com.example.myapplication.activity.VideoPreviewActivity.access$600(VideoPreviewActivity.java:66)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.871 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at
> com.example.myapplication.activity.VideoPreviewActivity$6$1.run(VideoPreviewActivity.java:421)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.871 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.872 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.872 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.873 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7403)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.874 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.874 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.874 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.875 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed:
> ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.875 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.875 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at
> libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.875 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at
> libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.875 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at
> libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.875 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7302)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.875 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
> 2021-04-08 20:11:26.875 23095-23095/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:   ... 12 more

Comment: How have you added the file into your device? Could you post your manifest, too?

Comment: i do create a video directory for save video & add my manifest file

Comment: Sometime I had your same problem, it was how I crete files. That's due to permission (not those we give in manifest). Try to create a file inside external storage, on a button click. If it can be opened...that's the problem

Comment: Can you give me any code or demo or link?

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66276593/filenotfoundexception-when-trying-to-screenshot/66276958#66276958)

Comment: This is work.Thank you..