# Open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) in android Q and Targeting android 11

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am getting **open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)** error in android Q only while using scope storage access framework. The app is working fine on android 11 but getting this error on android Q only.
Here is my code:

```
 val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
                    type = "text/xml"
                    addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                    //Adding Read URI permission
                    flags = flags or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                }
                startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_XML_FILE_REQUEST)




  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(requestCode == OPEN_XML_FILE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            data?.data?.let { documentUri ->

                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
                    //Permission needed if you want to retain access even after reboot
                    contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                        documentUri,
                        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    )

                   //getting real path by using Handle Path Oz
                    handlePathOz.getRealPath(documentUri)
                }

            }
        }


override fun onRequestHandlePathOz(pathOz: PathOz, tr: Throwable?) {
    val path = pathOz.path
    //gets the real path of file, now getting the file content and opening it in an editor
}
```

In order to get real path of file i have used *Handle Path Oz* because from **documentUri** i was unable to get real path of file. Here is [library](https://github.com/onimur/handle-path-oz)

**Note:** Please Don't suggest for to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml file as google playstore does not allowed it now while **targeting android SDK 30**

Comment: `using scope storage access framework. ` Nice. Now we have SSAF.

Comment: `flags = flags or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` It makes no sense to add that flag. Please remove.

Comment: `//from documentUri getting the path and doing my job
                   //Getting an error while trying to open or read the file
                }` Why is that code missing?  Post complete code. The code that does not work. It looks already wrong if you write 'getting the path'.

Comment: I have edit the code, please take a look into it

Comment: Not much more info. Still no code. And `//gets the real path of file, now getting the file content and opening it in an editor
}` I already told you that it looked wrong when you wrote getting the path. It is indeed very wrong trying to get a path to read the file. As you can use the obtained uri to open an inputstream for that uri and then read from the stream.

Comment: InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream (documentUri);

Comment: In this case InputStream make a sense we can read xml file content through it becuase xml file is just like txt file but what about pdf file, csv or mht format file. How can we read pdf file? etc

Comment: You can read them from that stream too. What is the problem? Otherwise you would read them from a FileInputStream i think. Do it from the InputStream directly.

Comment: After getting the path through Ion getting file content, the file could be of any type       Ion.with(this)
            .load(File(path))
            .asString()
            .setCallback { e, result ->
  // result variable have content of the file
            }

Comment: `only while using scope storage access framework. ` As said before that has nothing to do with scoped storage. Only with you trying to get a path from an uri. There is SAF but no SSAF ;-). Please get it!

Comment: Dear sir, i'm getting your point but the problem is i need file in many case and from documentUri i am not getting the file. With handle Path OZ library i am getting the actual file path which is ok. But in android 10 without `requestLegacyExternalStorage` i am getting **open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**  and with `requestLegacyExternalStorage` in manifest the app is working fine.

Comment: Hope this could help you:
[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67015541/when-create-a-directory-in-android-10-app-crash-but-android-11-its-work-well?noredirect=1#comment118619170_67015541)